# Error importing assimp library

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I need to convert a .dae file to .obj for a work I'm doing in C#. I only found this library that seems to work but when I start the program it crashes.
I imported it going to Project > Add Reference and then choosing the AssimpNet.dll file in assimp-net-master\AssimpNet\bin\Net20-Debug.
It gives me this error:

> Assimp.AssimpException occurred HResult=0x80131500 Message=Error
>   loading unmanaged library from path: Assimp32.dll, see inner exception
>   for details. The specified module could not be found. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x8007007E)

This is my code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AssimpContext context = new AssimpContext();
        String colladaPath = "lamp.dae";
        Scene ducky = context.ImportFile(colladaPath);
        ExportDataBlob blob = context.ExportToBlob(ducky, "obj");
    }
```